# GCP Is there way to type in firewall rules only accept traffic from US addresses?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

There is a huge list of US ips here

https://lite.ip2location.com/united-states-of-america-ip-address-ranges

We want to constrain some servers to US only ips but not sure we can do that with google's firewall rules or not?  Anyone know if this is possible?

thanks,
Dean

Comment: When I want to see the product available on Google Store US, I use a free VPN and I can access to it (I'm located in France). So, my question: is it really relevant to filter on IP location?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use [Google Cloud Armor security policies](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies#creating-policy-rules), where you can configure policy for certain [rules and expressions](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/rules-language-reference#expression-examples). Based on the rule you can [allow or deny](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/configure-security-policies#create-example-policies) traffic.

The region codes are based on the [ISO 3166-1 alpha 2 codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2). In some cases, a region corresponds to a country, but this is not always the case. For example, the US code includes all states of the United States, one district, and six outlying areas.

The following expression matches against requests from the region US and within specified IP range:

> origin.region_code == 'US’ && inIpRange(origin.ip, '1.2.3.0/24')